# VBA, Autofill filling series instead of copying cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use Autofill to Copy Cells down, It works fine for String type records, but numeric numers it is filling the series.

Before the code runs:

[image]

After the code runs:

[image]

I want it to fill down 0's.

Here is my code:

```
sh.Range("G" & lastR1, PreviousColumn & lastR1).AutoFill _
   Destination:=sh.Range("G" & lastR1, PreviousColumn & lastR)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use value transfer:

```
With sh
   .Range("G" & lastR1, PreviousColumn & lastR).Value = _
   .Range("G" & lastR1, PreviousColumn & lastR1).Value
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

To fill down zeros, simply set the value to zero instead of using Autofill.
Use a single line of code, `[a2:a5] = [a1].value` for example, to set a range of cells all to the same value.